# Magento Display zero price as custom text

Tags: magento-1.9

Is it possible to change the text when the price is 0.00?

I need to switch from 0.00 to FREE, at all zero value prices

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternative way for overriding template. Use below code. It will work.

**Option 1.**

**app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox">
        <plugin name="MyVendor_MyModule_change_template" type="MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin\FinalPricePlugin" />
</type>
```

**MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin\FinalPricePlugin.php**

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin;

class FinalPricePlugin
{
    public function beforeSetTemplate(\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $subject, $template)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $enable=$objectManager->create('MyVendor\MyModule\Helper\Data')->chkIsModuleEnable();
        if ($enable) {
            if ($template == 'Magento_Catalog::product/price/final_price.phtml') {
                return ['MyVendor_MyModule::product/price/final_price.phtml'];
            } 
            else
            {
                return [$template];
            }
        } else {
            return[$template];
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2.**

override below file

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

and put in your theme

> app/code/Your/Theme/Magento_Catalog/view/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

and in final_price.phtml you can add your logic as per need. :)

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: hi! Thanks for the answer, but is for magento 1.9, can u help me?